# Unable to execute stream analytics job in azure after particular time

Tags: azure

I have created a stream analytics job to send data from event hub to cosmos DB. I am getting error while running the job now. The details are not passed to cosmosDB as expected. The error says "Service error" and the message I am receiving in output is "details are temporarily unavailable". Also I am using free trial subscription. Is the issue related to subscription or time zone of stream job. Not sure about it? Can anyone suggest the solution?